# Inverse/Reverse of Html.fromHtml(String)

Tags: android, html, android-edittext, textview

I am creating a note application for myself. To style my notes, I write html tags, click a button and show styled version with html. from html.. But the problem is, I need to store the text with html tags not without it so when I get the data from the database, I get the text with style.

So I wonder is there any way to decode embedded html tags  other than storing the string before html. from html function and acting accordingly? Also i can click the button anytime then continue typing which is very hard to track. Because i run this function to stylize ;

```
text.setText(Html.fromHtml(text.getText().toString()));
```

Which means i lose the tag info.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why `Html` at all? are you aware of `Spannable` interface?

Comment: @pskink yes i know but then there are two problems; You cant store span info in the database and i need to do it in text watcher functions(such as using Pattern and matcher functions to find tags.). Is there any shorter way?

Comment: so store their description: start, end, type, any additional params of the span

Comment: yeah it is a way and i hope it is not only way =). Because when i show it stylized i need to remove tags from text  because span does not remove them (html does.) Also html does not hold the info of new line which is my new problem now. I hoped there was a shorter way.

Answer (score 0):

If the user of the app write the html tags, the app should store them.

So as you suggest yourself, you will have to store the string before calling `Html.fromHtml`.

Comment: The button i mentioned  runs the function text.setText(Html.fromHtml(text.getText().toString())); so the tags are lost. Also user can click the button anytime then continue string which is very hard to track.

Comment: Well keep them. You can use a field in your Activity or Fragment to keep the string with the tag. Or even have your own custom text field wich can display string using Html.fromHtml or showing the tags